# How to combine two or more formulas

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to combine three such formulas `=IF(AND(A3=2),"1")`and `=IF(AND(B3=2),"2")`and `=IF(AND(C3=2),"3")` in one cell.

Goal:

- if A3 has 2 then return 1
- if B3 then 2, and
- if C3 has 2 then 3

Number 2 doesn't repeat in any of the cells.

Tried like this but doesn't work: `=IF(A3="2",1,IF(B3="2",2,IF(C3="2",3)))`

This returns `FALSE`; it should not.

Any pointers?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? And what are you trying to achieve with `=IF(AND(A3=2),"1")`? Please show an example of input and desired output.

Comment: It says FALSE
I want, if there is number 2 in any of those three cells then it put 1,2,3 according their oder i.e (if A3 has 2 then 1, if B3 then 2, and if C3 has 2 then 3)
Number 2 doesn't repeat in all three cells.
I hope it clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a number 2, then it shouldn't be in quotes...
And `FALSE` is the default return when it doesn't match (i.e. the default ELSE) - you need to specify what you want if you want something else...

```
=IF(A3=2,1,IF(B3=2,2,IF(C3=2,3,"not found")))
```